# Palatino text with CMR math in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-mode

I've tried so many combinations, but I can't get it to work. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could you include a small example of what you've tried?

Comment: Palatino and Computer Modern don't mix well with each other; the result will be something like a punch in the eye. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `serif` option to set the default family to roman, then set `\rmdefault` and `\mathfamilydefault` as you please:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{pplx}
\renewcommand\mathfamilydefault{cmr}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle}
  Some text\\
  $E=mc^2$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*Note: Next time, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) outlining at least one of the 'many combinations' you tried ;-)*

Comment: Also, if you want Palatino with oldstyle figures, you can set `\rmdefault` to `pplj`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I won't post stuff I tried so as not to confuse anybody, but I actually inherited a template that was using the `pxfonts` package and I was trying to find a way to change only the math font.

Comment: @user24121 »I won't post stuff I tried« - Please _do_ post stuff that you tried if you ask a question! This is _always_ helpful for people answering.